# Get <table> element's nth <td> innerHTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml, dom

Is there anyway I can get the innerHTML of the designated n<sup>th</sup> <td> in a <table> using JavaSCript?

Since my table is automatically generated, my <td>'s do not have IDs.  I am using the following HTML code:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="myTD()">Cell 1</td>
    <td onmouseover="myTD()">Cell 2</td>
    <td onmouseover="myTD()">Cell 3</td
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="myTD()">Cell 4</td>
    <td onmouseover="myTD()">Cell 5</td>
    <td onmouseover="myTD()">Cell 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But how do access, for instance, Cell 5?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify when (on load, on hovering, ...) and where (client side, server side ...) you want to do that?

If you need the cell inside myTD, just use the **this** keyword, which happens to be your HTMLTableCell:

```
function myTD() {
   this.style.color="red"; // just for the example, using CSS classes is much better
}
```

Comment: Alright, I need to get the .innerHTML of the TD element.  I tried this.innerHTML but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I got it working.  But I had to pass (this) through the onmouseover="myTD(this)" and the function myTD(this) to get it to work...

Comment: What browser did you test it with ?

Answer (score 14):

```
var cells = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
```

This will contain all your table cells. Use array notation to access a specific one:

```
cells[4]
```

Here's a quick demo which changes the background color:

http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/W7RAu/

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  I'll try it out right now...  Didn't think of this simple solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want - Dom: document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[2].cells[1]

Answer (score 2):

Pass the cell back to the function:

`<td onmouseover="myTD(this)">Cell 1</td>`

Get the innerhtml from the object:

```
function myTD(obj) {
    alert(obj.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just CSS you could do:

```
#table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)
{
    background:#ff0000;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dGf8k/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
function addClassToNthTD(n) {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');

    for (var i = 0; i < table.childNodes.length; i++;) {
        var rows = table.childNodes[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < tr.childNodes.length; j++;) {
            n = n - 1;
            if (n == 0) {
                tr.childNodes[j].className = 'foo';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$('td')
```

Places all of the `td` elements in the code into a zero-based array, so the cell with 'Cell 5' as its content would be the fifth element of that array, ie:

```
$('td')[4]
```

[jQuery also accepts CSS style selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), so if you wanted to target the every second cell in a row, you could use a selector such as:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(2)')
```

Read through the selector documentation I've linked, it can come in very handy for situations like this

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but if you want to do some kind of "hover" ability, jquery can do that quite simple. i have created an example Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fd3GK/1/