# Javascript - How to select "x" row

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I have this list made on sweetalert2

[image: listado]

*** this is the code ***

```
 function detalleTransf(matricula, bancoorigenTransf, cbu_cta_origen, titular_cta_origen, ultimos_digitos_cta_origen) {

        var datosTransferencia = {{ datosTransferencia|json_encode|raw }} ;



        let html = "<html><body>"

            html += "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-hover table-condensed no-border'>" +
                "<tr class='encabezado-tabla'> <td class='text-center'>Seleccionar </td><td class='text-center'> Matricula</td><td class='text-center'> Banco de Origen</td><td class='text-center'>CBU Cuenta Origen</td><td class='text-center'>Titular Cuenta Origen</td><td class='text-center'>Últimos 5 Dígitos Cuenta Origen</td> </tr>";

                for (let row of datosTransferencia) {

                    html += "<tr id='algo'><td class='text-center'><div class='radio'><input type='checkbox' name='check' value='value' id='regular'  onclick='prueba()' ><label style='display: none'>" + "</div></label></td>";

                    html += "<td class='text-center'>" + matricula + "</td>";

                    html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_banco + "</td>";

                    html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_cbu + "</td>";

                    html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_titular + "</td>";

                    html += "<td class='text-center'>" + row.transf_ctaorigen + "</td></tr>";

                }

            html += "</table></div>";

            html += "</body></html>";
        return html;
    };
```

with this function I select each cell of a specific row and insert it into an input field

```
  function test() {
        var value1 =  document.getElementById("bancoorigenTransf").innerText.replace(/\s+/, "");
        var value2 =  document.getElementById("cbu_cta_origen").innerText.replace(/\s+/, "");
        var value3 =  document.getElementById("bancoorigenTransf").innerText.replace(/\s+/, "");
        var input = $('#titularorigen666');
        var input2 = $('#cbuorigen');
        var input3 = $('#bancoorigen');
        input.val(input.val() + value1 + ', ');
        input2.val(input2.val() + value2 + ', ');
        input3.val(input3.val() + value3 + ', ');
        return false;
    };
```

The error I have is that it always selects the *first row* only.

the only solution i could think of is to add a **unique id** to it in the for loop but i don't know how to do it or if there is a better solution

Comment: in this example it does the task perfectly .. the problem is when there are two "checks" since it keeps selecting the first one ...  http://jsfiddle.net/4rvoydnq/

Answer (score 0):

One answer to this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365819/6456163), if you are only interested in getting the `nth` row of a table via JavaScript:

```js
var cells = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
```

This will contain all your table cells. Use array notation to access a specific one:

```js
cells[4]
```

Here's a quick demo which changes the background color:

http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/W7RAu/

Comment: the thing with the example you passed is that you selected an entire row... the exercise is to select a row + of each row select the information of a cell of that row and pass it to an input .
http://jsfiddle.net/4rvoydnq/      
in this example it does it perfect but it only reads the first row and if a new one is added to it it doesn't care, it only reads the first row

Comment: @luis I don't understand what you mean, are you saying you would like the code modified to select specific columns from within the selected row?

Comment: the exercise is: having two checkboxes .. choose one and send the cell information to an input .. in the jsfiddle there is only one checkbox, because when I add another one it takes the information from the first one

Comment: Your jsfiddle example doesn't have any tables, so I don't know what you mean by "it takes the information from the first one." Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you hope to accomplish so I can modify my code to help you out